# Selenium firefox webdriver: set download.dir for a pdf

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried several solution around nothing really works or they are simply outdated.

Here my webdriver profile

```
let firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
let profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", 'C:\\MYDIR');
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf","application/x-pdf", "application/acrobat", "applications/vnd.pdf", "text/pdf", "text/x-pdf", "application/vnd.cups-pdf");
```

I simply want to download a file and **set the destination path**. It looks like `browser.download.dir` is ignored.

That's the way I download the file:

```
function _getDoc(i){
    driver.sleep(1000)
        .then(function(){
            driver.get(`http://mysite/pdf_showcase/${i}`);
            driver.wait(until.titleIs('here my pdf'), 5000);

        })
}
for(let i=1;i<5;i++){
    _getDoc(i);
}
```

The page contains an iframe with a pdf. I can gathers the src attribute of it, but with the iframe and `pdfjs.disabled=true` simply visits the page `driver.get()` causes the download (so I'm ok with it).

The only problem is the download dir is ignored and **the file is saved in the default download firefox dir**.

**Side question**: if I wrap `_getDoc()` in a for loop for that parameter `i` how can I be sure I won't flood the server? If I use the same driver instance (just like everyone usually does) the requests are sequentials?